# Using a wildcard in a PHP variable when checking its value

Tags: php

I have a variable called $flex and its value could be "yes" or "no."

I also could have any of the following variables also that could be "yes" or "no":

- $flex1
- $flex2
- $flex3
- and so on up to $flex99.

I have code that needs to check if EITHER $flex is equal to "yes" or if ANY OF THE NUMBER VARIANTS is equal to "yes."

So it would be something like:

```
if ($flex == "on" || $flex{**ANY # 1 thru 99**} == "on"){
//do something
}
```

Is this doable without looping from 0 to 99? If so, does it require using REGEX?

Comment: What you *really* need is to nest these values in the proper data structure - an array, instead of discrete variables - this would make this chuck much, *much* easier.

Comment: Dare I ask why you have 99 variables? It's hard to envisage what the sceanrio is. It would make more sense to put all this data in an array, perhaps.

Comment: If you find yourself appending sequential numbers to variables, that's a strong signal that they should be in an array. Short answer to the actual question as-asked: No, but if it was an array you could loop over the values, do your tests, and then act based on the result.